# Adding Context Menu To Desktop Background

Tags: c#, contextmenu, desktop

I have a program that I want to run in the system tray. While my program is running I want to provide the user with a context menu whenever they click on the desktop.

For example, let's say the user clicks on the desktop (not on any folder, icon, etc., only on the desktop). I would provide them with a context menu such as:

[image: wallpaper context menu screenshot]

I know how to add these using a registry file (.REG):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Wallpaper]
"MUIVerb"="Wallpaper Settings"
"SubCommands"="Next;Previous;Reset"
"Position"="bottom"

; Next
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Next]
@="Next"

; Previous
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Previous]
@="Previous"

; Reset
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Reset]
@="Reset"
```

I tried, in my program, to just add these entries to the registry but I kept running into permission problems because the program isn't running as administrator. I also don't want to force the end user of my program to run it as administrator.

How can I write a program that adds a context menu to the desktop background but doesn't have to run as administrator? Or can I?

Does my program have to run as a service?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of having the installer add the shell commands?

Comment: Yes I did think about that. Actually, I might go back and revise my original post and state that I don't want to have an installer. My program just needs to run (from an .exe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the .REG file during installation.

or

Provided, you make your installer yourself:

```
var path = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Next";
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(path, true); // True makes it writeable
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path).SetValue("@", "Reset", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
```

.

Thankfully, no way of doing this w/o administrative privs.

Comment: I have decided against using an installer if at all possible. Do you think this can be done (the registry changes, etc.) at runtime?

Comment: Sure. You could go sneaky though, and do it on next OS boot using autostart, background service... Ooh and it make take a while to see the effect. Probably next boot.

Comment: Accepting the answer is appreciated. Talking about services, if your program runs all the time, I bet there is a way to intercept mouse-desktop interactions, maybe a gesture of some sort, not to deprive the user of traditional context-menu.

Comment: It's actually preety interesting subject, I'll have a look into this now.

Comment: I don't want to accept your first answer because I have decided against using an installer (for now at least). Unless I can be convinced otherwise.

Comment: I made some research, and there's preety straightforward way to get user's clicks and mouse movements on the desktop and all desktop icons. You might consider changing your plan about this, or run my original answer only on the first run of your exe. If you're interested, write here.

Comment: I think I would like to go the route of getting the user's clicks on the desktop. But I still don't see how to add/modify the context menu that's already there. I could probably popup my own context menu but I want it to popup with the others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44995/discussion-between-user1654381-and-jan-tacci)